# Windows form Button appearance is getting changed while running application

Tags: winforms, windows-controls

I am working on a Windows form Application, came up with some weird behavior.
The appearance of all the buttons in the form are getting changed when running the application using Visual Studio.

For example : 
Button style and Appearance at Design time,

[image]

While at runtime Buttons look like as below,

[image]

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Probably taking the same default look as your other Windows UI elements?

Comment: it may be a possibility, but then which settings needs to be change?

Comment: It is the "classic" look, the designer always assumes that Visual Styles are enabled.  Like they normally are, look at your Main() entrypoint in program.cs.  The  Application.EnableVisualStyles() call is expected to be present there.

Comment: Thank you @hans-passant ,  This is a valid point. But I recheck "Main()" entrypoint of the application, "Application.EnableVisualStyles()" is present there.
The other point is, I am using Telerik win controls as well in the application. Is there any case where windows controls and Telerik controls are conflicting and causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the call to:

```
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
```

When added, in Main before displaying the Form you will get your expected behavior.
If you are exporting this form in a dll you can still add this call inside the constructor of the form.